# Leibniz notation convention for a differential equation involving a function called 'd(t)'

Tags: derivatives, notation

I am composing a report on electromagnetism in nanomagnets. I need to construct a differential equation involving the differentiable portions of [this function](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-dt-function-to-get-the-Lyapunov-exponent_fig1_274831956) for an error analysis metric (Lyapunov exponent).

Unfortunately, the function is called ***d(t)***
and I need to write an expression involving its derivative with respect to time.

I would much prefer not to switch to another notation such as $$\dot d$$ or $$d'(t)$$ since I have already used Leibniz notation throughout the entirety of my report and because I need the flexibility of Leibniz's notation that allows multiplying and dividing by ***dt***.

What would be the best way to write this using Leibniz's notation without sparking confusion?

$$\frac{d}{dt}d(t)$$
$$\frac{dd}{dt}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(d(t))$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set the differential d’s upright, like so:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}d}{\mathrm{d}t}.
$$
You should probably do that everywhere in that case. (I like doing that anyways.)

Other than that, you can try simply pointing it out the first time. (“For conventional reasons, the function is called $d$. We apologize for the unfortunate clash with the diffential operator.”)